# How to make a unity game easily-moddable?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, dll, game-development

I've seen many unity games get modded, but usually using external tools like thunderstore and whatnot. Here is how I want my mod system to work:

When my game opens, it reads a file from Appdata/locallow/myGame/Mods/myMod/ a code file, not data files like json. Example method in that file:

```cs
override void Start()
{
    MyGame.RegisterItem("Example item name", "example_item_name")
}
```

Then when my unity game detects this method is called, it runs some unity code. Is this possible if so how, and if not how close can I get?
I've heard of the CSC and roselyn but I can't get those to work in unity, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp cannot be resolved despite me installing the nuget package.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No that's my old question, but it was closed and never opened (thanks stack overflow community). It didn't recieve an answer

Comment: Did you read the reason the question was closed? This one is the same so it can be closed for the same reason. You should fix the problem with the original question not repost it with the same problem.

Comment: I did but no-one reviewed it .-.

Comment: It is still very very broad. Better suited to a more discussion based forum.

Comment: Make your game open source, let modders do the rest of works.

Comment: the problem with your question is, that it's way too broad. You can post it again and again, that won't change. All we could do is give you some very vague tips, like writing your own code-parser (or use Roslyn). How to use these is simply too broad to put into a simple answer here.

Comment: Well I don't know anything about this topic, so I don't know how to narrow it down, please give whatever help you can

Comment: The simplest approach is to design your game using a data-driven approach, allowing you to iterate on the game content through the designed framework. This way, you can directly reference this framework in the modular system, enabling others to modify game content using JSON. If you want to do more, such as adding new program functionalities, as far as I understand, module creators must ensure that the designed DLL can match your game program, handle more API definitions, and consider how to integrate the independent DLL functionalities into the game.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I got it. I put a file in LocalAppData/Company/Game/file.cs which looks like this

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyMod
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Debug.Log("Some output");
        }
    }

}
```

The part I was struggling with is getting the roslyn compiler working in unity. But I just need to use [this](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) to install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, from where I could use the below script:

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;

public class ModCompilerBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        ModCompiler compiler = new ModCompiler();

        // Load the C# code from a file in Application.persistentDataPath
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "file.cs");
        string code = File.ReadAllText(path);

        // Compile the code into an assembly
        Assembly assembly = compiler.CompileAndLoad(code);

        Type type = assembly.GetType("MyMod.MyClass");
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        method.Invoke(instance, null);
    }
}
public class ModCompiler
{
    public Assembly CompileAndLoad(string code)
    {
        SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);

        string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        
        Assembly netstandard = Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51");
        MetadataReference netstandardReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(netstandard.Location);

        
        MetadataReference[] references = new MetadataReference[]
        {
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(UnityEngine.Debug).Assembly.Location),
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Runtime.GCSettings).Assembly.Location),
            netstandardReference
            // Add other necessary assemblies here
        };


        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            assemblyName,
            syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
            references: references,
            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                // Handle compilation failures
                IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                    diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                    diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                {
                    Debug.LogError(diagnostic.Id + diagnostic.GetMessage());
                }

                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Be very careful about what you allow user created mods to do. Allow unrestricted code to run and inevitably someone will make a mod that erases hard drives or files, installs viruses, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dictionary to save functions against a string tag: [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-func-delegate)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;    

static int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
static int Sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

Dictionary<String, Func<int,int, int>> methods = new Dictionary<String, Func<int, int, int>>();
int start()
{
   
    Func < int, int, int> addFunc = Add;
    Func < int, int, int> subFunc = Sub;
    methods.Add("ItemOne", addFunc);
    methods.Add("ItemTwo", subFunc);

    if (methods.ContainsKey("ItemOne"))
    {
       int value = methods["ItemOne"](5,10);
       Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    if (methods.ContainsKey("ItemTwo"))
    {
        int value = methods["ItemTwo"](5, 10);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }


    Console.ReadLine();
    return 1;
}


start();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How on earth does this fit OPs question? What does this have to do with "modding" a game by user-created source-code?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain "When my game opens, it reads a file from Appdata/locallow/myGame/Mods/myMod/ a code file, not data files like json. Example method in that file:
Then when my unity game detects this method is called, it runs some unity code. Is this possible if so how, and if not how close can I get?" - OP

Comment: I can read that question, however you didn't provide anything about what your dictionary has to do with a source-code-file. I still have no clue how this relates to a code-parser.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain because you can dynamically compile and add code to your current program?